# Accidently Delete Some Index Databese Tables

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

My magento version is 1.9.3.7. Today I try to clean my database. And I accidently truncate catalog_product_index_price and catalog_product_index_eav tables. I always have backup but only in this database backup broken. Now in backend I can see all products but no price,no name,no attributes.

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Those index tables could be regenerated again once you reindex magento.

Go to the admin section -> System -> Index Management -> Reindex All

Or you could use [magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) command line instead.

Go to your root project folder and type the following:

```
./n98-magerun.phar index:reindex:all
```